# Uploaded image can't be saved in to folder and the image can't be view in folder when running web under IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have project to upload image and view image on asp.net.  everything work as i expected. i can upload image and saved to my folder then saved the folder to database, then from database i can show or view the image.

Unfortunately, after publishing to IIS and run the web UNDER IIS , image that i uploaded won't saved to folder and also the image that contains on my folder can't be viewed when running web under IIIS.

I tried to search in stackoverflow how to solve it and everyone said it's about permission i have tried option to set the security permission but nothing works

*Folder settings:*

[image: SECURITY PERMISSION SETTING]

*Subfolder settings:*

[image: FOLDER TO SAVE]

Comment: `image that i uploaded won't saved to folder` but what happens instead? do you get an exception?

Comment: Are you sure that the site is running under the user `DefaultAppPool`? Normally it would be `IIS_IUSRS` (also present in the list).

Comment: Even if you have a the default appPool, it might be running under a different identity,

Comment: What's the authentication method? If anonymous, grant the anonymous user those permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it could be perhaps a wrong path as your app is installed under the default web site... I often suggest to alwyAs start from the exact thing that happens to avoid guessing about issues.

Edit: the folder structure is really strange. It seems I have the default web site, created an application root under this web site but your main ScraBoy app volder is still under this folder ??? I believe I installed app one level below what you intended